# How to read the benefits table

Tags: united-states, health-insurance

I am not a regular on this site, so I apologize if I have the wrong format, but I am having trouble understanding some of the health insurance benefits and costs tables that I am seeing in my search for cheaper insurance. My question involves the boxes that mention a percentage after deductible,such as "100% after deductible" or "80% after deductible". Does this mean that I would be responsible for paying the percentage (100% or 80%) after deductible or does that show how much the insurance pays (so I would be paying 0% and 20% respectively)? I am asking because there are other cells in the table that say "Covered 100%"so the lack of the word 'covered' in the ones that mention a deductible has me a little worried.

[This question](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/53822/76308) has a mention of coinsurance, which the table I am looking at does not. I am also unfamiliar with the legal implications of posting a screen shot of the table, even though it is publicly available, so if it is legal and it would help you guys to see it please let me know in the comments so I can upload it. Thanks.

As per the comments, [here](https://selecthealth.org/plans/individual-and-family/-/media/E514A78955A14D67903C82553185B15D.ashx) is the link to the pdf. The table I am looking at is on page 8-9 (5 on the pdf).

Comment: If the information is publicly available, there should be no issue with you linking to it. Also, I'm pretty sure it means x% covered by insurance, after you meet your deductible, i.e. you'd be responsible for 0%/20%.

Comment: For what it's worth, after working professionally with benefits for over 10 years, benefits information is still the hardest to comprehend, especially health insurance.

Comment: @Brandon Thanks, I work in computers, so this is all foreign to me, glad to know it is not just me who has issues with it. They should work to make it clearer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"100% after deductible" means that you pay nothing once you have met your deductible.

"80% after deductible" means that you pay 20% once you have met your deductible.

"Covered 100%" means that you pay nothing for these services at any time.

Comment: Thanks, I was a little worried that since there are no labels, and the copays are just listed, that everything mentioned was what I would have to pay.